Pandas group and transform
i have a dataframe that is generated by:
df = pd.DataFrame({'date' : [*['2020-01-01']*3, *['2020-01-02']*3, *['2020-01-03']*3], 
                   'id' : ['A1', 'A2', 'A3']*3, 
                   'qty' : [50, 10, 20, 40, 10, 20, 40, 15, 25]
                  }).sort_values('date')

I would like to get a new column 'delta' which is the difference of quantity from each date/id. I thought that
df['delta'] = df.groupby(['date', 'id'])['qty'].transform(lambda x: x.diff()).sort_index() would work but i get:
date    id  qty variation
0   2020-01-01  A1  50  NaN
1   2020-01-01  A2  10  NaN
2   2020-01-01  A3  20  NaN
3   2020-01-02  A1  40  NaN
4   2020-01-02  A2  10  NaN
5   2020-01-02  A3  20  NaN
6   2020-01-03  A1  40  NaN
7   2020-01-03  A2  15  NaN
8   2020-01-03  A3  25  NaN

where as i was expected to get:
date    id  qty variation
0   2020-01-01  A1  50  NaN
1   2020-01-01  A2  10  NaN
2   2020-01-01  A3  20  NaN
3   2020-01-02  A1  40  -10
4   2020-01-02  A2  10  0
5   2020-01-02  A3  20  0
6   2020-01-03  A1  40  0
7   2020-01-03  A2  15  5
8   2020-01-03  A3  25  5

Any suggestion?

The issue with your approach is that transform is applied to each group independently, so it calculates the difference within each group, but not across different groups with the same date. To achieve the desired result, you can use groupby with diff.
Corrected code:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': [*['2020-01-01']*3, *['2020-01-02']*3, *['2020-01-03']*3], 
    'id': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3']*3, 
    'qty': [50, 10, 20, 40, 10, 20, 40, 15, 25]
}).sort_values('date')

df['variation'] = df.groupby('id')['qty'].diff().fillna(0)

Ouput:
        date    id  qty variation
0   2020-01-01  A1  50  0.0
1   2020-01-01  A2  10  0.0
2   2020-01-01  A3  20  0.0
3   2020-01-02  A1  40  -10.0
4   2020-01-02  A2  10  0.0
5   2020-01-02  A3  20  0.0
6   2020-01-03  A1  40  0.0
7   2020-01-03  A2  15  5.0
8   2020-01-03  A3  25  5.0


Here's another way to do it using dataframe reshaping:
df.set_index(['date', 'id']).unstack(1).diff().stack(dropna=False).reset_index()

Output:
         date  id   qty
0  2020-01-01  A1   NaN
1  2020-01-01  A2   NaN
2  2020-01-01  A3   NaN
3  2020-01-02  A1 -10.0
4  2020-01-02  A2   0.0
5  2020-01-02  A3   0.0
6  2020-01-03  A1   0.0
7  2020-01-03  A2   5.0
8  2020-01-03  A3   5.0

